# Volume of a lighthouse given height and diameters

Tags: calculus, integration

Give a lighthouse of height 90 feet, with diameters of 45 feet and 30 feet at the bottom and top respectively, what would the volume be. The lighthouse isn't a perfect cone, part of the top is cut off.

I know that the integral would be $$\int_{0}^{90} \pi r^2 dx$$

The radius would be the slope of the edge times the height on the lighthouse which would be $$45-\frac{15x}{180}$$ so the final integral is $$\int_{0}^{90} \pi \left(45-\frac{15x}{180}\right)^2 dx$$

Is my logic correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: Note that the radius is the diameter divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the radius is equal to the diameter divided by $2$.
In order to formalize this a bit, you can write the radius as a function of $z$ (a convex linear combination of the two radii): 
$$r(z) = \frac{45}{2}(1-\frac{z}{90}) + \frac{30}{2}\frac{z}{90}, z \in [0,90]$$ 
And then integrate:
$$\int_{0}^{90}{\pi r^2(z)\,dz} = \pi\int_{0}^{90}{(\frac{45}{2}(1-\frac{z}{90}) + \frac{30}{2}\frac{z}{90})^2\,dz}$$

Answer (score 0):

You're using the disk method to find the volume of that lighthouse. Therefore, you're going to use this formula: $V=\pi\int_{a}^{b}[r(x)]^2\,dx$. Your radius function is going to be $r(x)=\frac{45/2-15}{90}x+15=\frac{1}{12}x+15$ where $\frac{1}{12}$ is the slope of the line crossing the $y$-axis at the point $y=15$ and going further up, if I understand the problem correctly. Your bounds of integration are from 0 to 90:

$$
V=\pi\int_{0}^{90}\left(\frac{1}{12}x+15\right)^2\,dx=\frac{64125\pi}{2}\ ft^3
$$

[Wolfram Alpha's answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+pi+*+(x%2F12+%2B+15)%5E2+dx+from+0+to+90).

As far as I'm able to comprehend the English language, the following must be the solid whose volume you're trying to find:

[image]

Comment: The diameter is not the radius.

Comment: oh yes, I overlooked that. Give me a second to fix that.

Comment: Also you took the cutoff cone flipped. If he wanted to integrate from the base $0$ to some random $x$ then yours would be from the top to some $x$.

Comment: I'll make a picture.

Comment: You don't have to make a picture, you can easily check that your $r$ doesn't produce the required length at both ends of the cone, by evaluating $r(0)$ and $r(90)$.

Comment: Could you explain how you got the (1/12)x+15?

Comment: 1/12 is the slope of that line. Can you see that from the graph that I've drawn? Slope is rise over run: $slope=\frac{rise}{run}$. The run is 90 and the rise is the $y$-difference between the points $15$ and $45/2$ which represent the top and bottom radii of the lighthouse.

Comment: Nvm, it's correct. $r(0) = 30/2$ and $r(90) = 45/2$ for you so it's correct.